# Undefined class DatabaseReference

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference productsRef = rootRef.child("products");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String product = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", product);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
productsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

But I'm getting these errors:

```
Undefined class DatabaseReference
Undefined class FirebaseDatabase
Undefined class DataSnapshot
```

etc..

Inside build.gradle(app) I have these implementations:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are u using flutter? Because their are plugins for firebase in flutter

Comment: Yes, I'm using Flutter

Comment: why dont u use the plugins here https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire?

Answer (score 2):

Add FlutterFire plugins in the `pubspec.yaml` file as shown below

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # Add the dependency for the Firebase Core Flutter SDK
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  firebase_database: ^3.1.0
```

follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) for more details